# Wordpress Help - Cant See What Include Code Is Doing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to help a friend who's original developer bailed on this site. The theme is Webicompanyz and I see its using the Contact Form 7 plugin. In one of the pages is the following code snippet:

[include_contact]

This is including a form, but i cant tell where from. All the form includes from the Contact Form 7 plugin are different and I dont see this form listed anywhere. How can I tell where this code snippet is pulling from?

Comment: "code snippet: [include_contact]" does not tell us anything. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing on this page is called a 'short code'. When WordPress reached one of these blocks it knows to fetch the missing content.

Short codes are widely used in plugins and widgets as an easy way to create dynamic content.

#### For your particular case

I would suggest viewing [documentation for Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/docs/)